# iterate mysql database from specific record

Tags: mysql

$pic = $DBcon->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_pictures WHERE type='holidays' ASC LIMIT 200");

Lets say my database has 500 records. If i use the query above, it starts at 200 and stops at the last record.

So the first 200 won't be searched, am I getting that right? If that is true, how do I have to write my query to start at record 200, go towards 500, and afterwards search records 0 - 200, too?

**note: as soon as one match was found, the iteration can stop. it's all just about the next picture**

Thank you guys :)

thats my database if necessary:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_pictures` (
  `picture_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `filename` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `title` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `description` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(60) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`picture_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you provide some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: _"So the first 200 won't be searched, am I getting that right?"_ - no, you did not get that right. WHERE is evaluated before LIMIT.

Comment: Did you try running this query? What result did you get?

Comment: no, i cannot provide any more data, but it's pretty simple. i want to start searching at a specific picture_id (my example was 200), and search for the closest picture in the database, which is type=holiday, too.

Comment: @CBroe: so you are saying all records will be searched, right?

Comment: Yes, of course. And if you only need one match, then use LIMIT 1, not 200, the latter makes no sense. If you want to find "the next" record of any kind, then you need to first of all specify what the order criterion is, and also provide a value that identifies the current record within that order. Your given query seems not even syntactically correct ... unless the method you are calling there applies further magic to the query string you pass in, `WHERE type='holidays' ASC` is just an SQL syntax error ...

Comment: "i want to start searching at a specific picture_id ..." - This is what you should write in your question. What you wrote instead is just confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for the next picture in a sequence where they're ordered by insertion ID:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_pictures WHERE picture_id>?
  ORDER BY picture_id LIMIT 1
```

`LIMIT` affects only the results given, not how many records are actually searched.